# How do I get a value in a BehaviorSubject to return within a getter?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

From my understanding, when you subscribe to a BehaviorSubject, that subscription is asynchronous. I am trying to get a value from an object within a BehaviorSubject and return that value in a getter. The getter needs to return the type 'number'. How do I approach this?

Below, I have a getter userId, which should return the user Id from an object held in the BehaviorSubject _loggedInUser

```js
export class AuthServiceService {

  private _loggedInUser: BehaviorSubject<LoggedInUserData> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient, 
    private storage: Storage
  ) { }


 /// This method below!!! --------------

  public get userId(): number{

    this._loggedInUser.pipe(
      take(1), 
      map(((loggedInUserData: LoggedInUserData) => {
        if(loggedInUserData){
          return loggedInUserData.user_id
        }
        return null;
      }))
    ).subscribe((userId: number | null) => {
      return userId;
    });
    
  }
  
 //// -----------------


  public doLogin(loginData: LoginFormData): Observable<any>{

    return this.http.post<LoggedInUserData>(`${authURL}/token`, loginData)
    .pipe(
      catchError(err => {

        if(err.status && err.status === 403)
          return throwError('The credentials you have entered are invalid or do not exist.');
        else
          return throwError('There was an issue processing your request.');

      }), 
      tap(respData => {

        console.log('LOGGED IN USER DATA: ', respData);

        this._loggedInUser.next(respData);
        this.storage.set('userData', respData);

      })
    );



  }


  public async autoLogin(){



  }


  public doLogout(){




  }





}
```

Comment: Did you try `_loggedInUser.value.user_id`? BehaviorSubject instance has a `value` property which gives the most recent value. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject

Comment: In this case, should I even be using a BehaviorSubject to hold user data?

Comment: BehaviorSubject is having a purpose. If you don’t need it then don’t use it. You can compose various observables as per your need.

Comment: "should I even be using a `BehaviorSubject` to hold user data?"  it would useful if you need the data to be accessible within your components

Comment: Your user data is loaded asynchronously so you have to ask yourself: If someone wants to access the `userId()` and no data is present yet, would it be ok if that someone received `null` when `userId()` is called even if 5ms later a userId is present? We use Observables when we want to access data and if it's not present wait until it's present or react to changing data. Working with Observables means returning Observables from a lot of functions and subscribing only when we need the actual data. In most cases you'd want `userId()` to return an Observable.

Answer (score 4):

Having an access to the Subject, you can obtain its value synchronously via `getValue()` mothod, as following:

```
public get userId(): number {
  return this._loggedInUser.getValue()?.userId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need the result synchronious, you should use the example as provided by Rafi Henig:

```js
    public get userId(): number {
      return this._loggedInUser.getValue()?.userId
    }
```

If you want it to be async, you could return an `Observable<number>` instead and use an async pipe in your html if you need to show it there. If not, you can subscribe to that Observable where you need it or keep the subscription if you want to track changes of the value. I am not sure if this is what you want, but here is an example of that:

```js
  public get userId(): Observable<number> {
    return this._loggedInUser.pipe(
      map((item) => item?.userId)
    );
  }
```

For HTML, use: `{{ userId | async }}` and for typescript code you can use:

```js
    this.userId.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((userId) => {
      console.log(userId);
    });
```

If you want to keep track the changes in your typescript, you should remove `take(1)` and simply `subscribe` to it. Remember to clean the subscription in `ngOnDestroy`.

Comment: pluck instead of map `this._loggedInUser.pipe(pluck('userId'))` would make more sense

Comment: @Stavm `pluck` will be deprecated in v7 an removed in v8 so using `map` isn't bad.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach - convert Observable to Promise, then use async/await:

```
const user = await this._loggedInUser.toPromise();
return user && user.userId;
```

Comment: Although, I don't think you can have an async getter.

Comment: yeah, missed it. Anyway, according to a lot of code inside the getter, for my sense it would better to convert it to method...but up to you :-). Use getValue() instead.